# how to set list item valuse property to correct Id from database tabel's row?

Tags: c#, database, drop-down-menu, listitem

I use entity Framework to connect to a database and retrieve some information from a table. I need to show this information in a drop down list. I need to set each list Item value equals to the Id which sets in database.

```
public void EducationDropDownListViewer()
{
    EducationDropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = "--select--", Value = "0" });
    List<Education> educations = ModelLists.GetEducationList();
    for (int i = 0; i < educations.Count; i++)
    {
        ListItem educationListItem = new ListItem();
        Education education = educations[i];
        educationListItem.Text = education.EducationName;
        educationListItem.Value = education.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        EducationDropdown.Items.Add(educationListItem);
    }
}
```

I expect the Id sets corresponding to each row's Id from DB, But It will set serially starts by 1. How I can set this property to correct value? I need to use this value which selects through this code to do some updates in database tables.

```
protected void EducationDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["educationid"] = Convert.ToInt32(EducationDropdown.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectedIndex` property return the progressive Index of the current select item in the whole DropDownList.
You are looking for the `SelectedValue` property that returns the `Value` of the `SelectedItem`

```
protected void EducationDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If you accept also the item at index zero (the prompt to select) then change
    // the test below to >=
    if(EducationDropDown.SelectedIndex > 0)
        ViewState["educationid"] = Convert.ToInt32(EducationDropdown.SelectedValue);
}
```